# Put data in 2nd row of a gridview(I need additional help!)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Put data in 2nd row of a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713196/put-data-in-2nd-row-of-a-gridview)

I have a gridview and i need to print the _fuelSurcharge in the 2nd row and the _rate in the first row.  Ive been trying `if(_row.RowIndex == 1)` inside the foreach and it still prints it all on the first row.

```
protected void grvbillDetail_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (GridViewRow _row in grvbillDetail.Rows)
    {
        decimal _fuelSurcharge =
            (_row.FindControl("txtFuelSurCharge")as TextBox).Text == string.Empty
            ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(
                (_row.FindControl("txtFuelSurCharge") as TextBox).Text);

        decimal _rate =
            (_row.FindControl("txtRate") as TextBox).Text == string.Empty
            ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(
                (_row.FindControl("txtRate") as TextBox).Text);

    }
}
```